# Trying to read text from text file using javascript but getting error on method: split

Tags: javascript

This is the code im using in my site:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/theme/jquery.newsTicker.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
    var file = "http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/theme/test.txt";
    $.get(file, function (txt) {
        var lines = txt.responseText.split("\n");
        $ul = $('<ul class="newsticker" />');
        for (var i = 0, len = lines.length; i < len; i++) {
            $ul.append('<li>' + lines[i] + '</li>');
        }
        $ul.appendTo('body').newsTicker({
            row_height: 48,
            max_rows: 2,
            speed: 6000,
            direction: 'up',
            duration: 400,
            autostart: 1,
            pauseOnHover: 0
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

There is nothing no text at all and it's not working.

This is my site:

```
http://newsxpressmedia.com/
```

When im browsing to my site in this case with chrome and then make:

Ctrl+Shift+J in the console that open i see this:

```
Consider using 'dppx' units instead of 'dpi', as in CSS 'dpi' means dots-per-CSS-inch, not dots-per-physical-inch, so does not correspond to the actual 'dpi' of a screen. In media query expression: only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), not all, not all, not all, only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi), only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) (index):1
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined (index):101
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.
```

How can i fix this 'split' error ?

** The text that is scrolling up and show in my site is other scripts/codes that work but this one in this question is not working.

** What i want to do is to use the jquery news ticker to read line by line from the text file and scroll it up with jquery. But this 'split' error i think make the problem that wont let it work.

EDIT**

Example how the text file im reading content format is:

```
Hello this is a line
דווח במקור בתאריך: 22.03.14  שעה : 20:11

Hello this is a line too
דווח במקור בתאריך: 22.03.14  שעה : 22:59
```

Each two lines are like a block so i want to show each time two lines scrolling up and then there is an empty line/space between each two groups of two lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dunno why you expect that `txt` had a `.responseText` property representing the text, but you should just use

```
    var lines = txt.split("\n");
```

Comment: This is working. But why i see the scrolling text on the lower left corner of my screen/site ? When i surf to my website at: http://newsxpressmedia.com/ i need to scroll with the mouse down and then i see it on the left lower corner. But i dragged the embed html into the middle of the page not to the left lower corner.

Comment: Maybe something with the text ?

Comment: Edited my question with showing how the text file format is.

Comment: The end of the page is just where you have placed the text: `$ul.appendTo('body').newsTicker()`. What do you mean by "you dragged the embed html into the middle of the page"?

Comment: Bergi im using weebly to edit my site. By dragging i mean a small window called html embed. Where i place this window in my page and add the code in this window there is where i see the code and rhe result like the scrolling of the text. That how it was so far. But now when i drag this window to the middle of the page like i did before the scrolling text i see it in the lower left corner. And not as before where i dragged the window to. I don't understand why its placing the scrolling text now in the lower/bottom left corner of the page in my web.

Comment: If i dont want to put it in : $ul.appendTo('body').newsTicker() but to decide alone where the text will be display in the page ? You can see what i mean in my site:  newsxpressmedia.com

Comment: You need to use `$ul.appendTo('div.wcustomhtml').newsTicker()` (or whatever selector you can use for the html you dragged there). Where the script is placed is irrelevant actually.